# Fetching Random Line From Flat Text File Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, random, flat-file

I am interested whether the following php script can be written in Javascript (or HTML5)? Basically that is just a simple file reading a .txt and displaying a random line from it:

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('flatFileDB.txt');
$textArray = explode("\n", $text);
$randArrayIndexNum = array_rand($textArray);
$randPhrase = $textArray[$randArrayIndexNum];
?>
<html>
<body>
<h2><?php echo $randPhrase; ?></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Example of 'flatFileDB.txt':

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
...
...
etc
```

The example is taken from here: http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1213, and I would like to do the same, but without server-side php. Is it even possible?

Comment: *Is it even possible?* Yes

Comment: Ok, now that we established that it's possible, let's find a solution.

Comment: Ajax call or file api, get text, split string on new lines, generate random number, pick index from array. Have fun coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the flat file DB can be accessed at `http://www.example.com/flatFileDB.txt` and your HTML file has a div with an id value of `random-phrase`:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() {
    // get the file contents
    var fileContent = this.responseText;
    // split into lines
    var fileContentLines = fileContent.split( '\n' );
    // get a random index (line number)
    var randomLineIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * fileContentLines.length );
    // extract the value
    var randomLine = fileContentLines[ randomLineIndex ];

    // add the random line in a div
    document.getElementById( 'random-phrase' ).innerHTML = randomLine;
};
request.open( 'GET', 'http://www.example.com/flatFileDB.txt', true );
request.send();
```

Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for the documentation on `XMLHttpRequest` which allows you to retrieve files asynchronously.

Comment: Sorry, I am a noob in JS - can you give me the code which would replace <?php echo $randPhrase; ?> ?

Comment: You cannot 'echo' in JS. You need to have an HTML element that you can change its value (eg. div / span)

Comment: @user3271739 I've added a solution for you.

Comment: So I should just put all this into <head> and then <div id="random-phrase"></div> somewhere into <body>?

Comment: Yes, inside `<script></script>` tags. And make sure that you've uploaded the DB file somewhere.

Comment: Thanks alkar for the help!

Comment: Another question, if I am not bothering too much? Any chance I assign a button to this request, so it would refresh the data on click?

Comment: @user3271739 get the button element (just like you get the div in the code above) and put all the above in a function in its `onload` attribute